# How to fix "TypeError: 'Member' object is not subscriptable" discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

So I am creating a gambling bot and I created a slots command. This command was previously working but then for some reason stopped, here is the code:

```
@client.command()
async def slots(ctx, amount=None):
     if amount == None:
         return await ctx.send("Please enter an amount you would like to bet!")
     
     await open_account(ctx.author)
     bal = await update_bank(ctx.author)

     amount = int(amount)

     if amount <50:
         return await ctx.send("You must bet at least $50")
     else:
         if amount>bal[0]:
            return await ctx.send("You don't have that much money")
         if amount <0:
             return await ctx.send("Amount must be larger than 0")
    
     final = []
     for i in range(3):
         a = random.choice(["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""])

         final.append(a)
    
     slotsEmbed = discord.Embed(title=f"{ctx.author.name}'s slots game")
     slotsEmbed.add_field(name="Your slots game", value=str(final))
     await ctx.send(embed=slotsEmbed)

     if final[0] == final[1] == final[2]:
        await update_bank(ctx.author, 3*amount)
        await ctx.send("You won all 3 slots!")

     elif final[0] == final[1] or final[0] == final[2] or final[1] == final[2]:
        await update_bank(ctx.author, 2*amount)
        await ctx.send("You won 2 slots!")
     else:
         await update_bank(ctx.author, -1*amount)
         await ctx.send("You didn't win any slots.")
```

The error occurs on line `if amount>bal[0]:`
This is just very odd to me because like I said this command was once working with this same exact code but for some reason it just stopped.

Here is the update_bank function:

```
async def update_bank(user,change = 0,mode = "Wallet"):
    users = await get_bank_data()

    users[str(user.id)][mode] += change 

    with open("mainbank.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(users, f, indent=4)

    bal = [users[str(user.id)]["Wallet"],users[str(user.id)]["Bank"]]
    return user
```

Comment: obviously, the question is, what does `update_bank` return

Comment: I added the update_bank function to the question, can you look at the edited question?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, in the update bank function for whatever reason I had return users which doesn't make sense since I want to change the balance of the user. I ended up changing it from "return users" to "return bal" and that fixed my problem!